# JavaFX build error when using expression binding?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

```
<Pane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="900.0" style="-fx-background-color: rgba(0, 100, 100, 0.1);" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <TitledPane fx:id="title" prefHeight="8.0" prefWidth="${title.parent.width}" text="Yeet" />
      <AnchorPane fx:id="main" layoutY="25.0" prefHeight="${main.parent.height - title.height}" prefWidth="${main.parent.width}" />
   </children>
</Pane>
```

The problem is that when I try to compile this including the lines `prefHeight="${main.parent.height - title.height}` or `main.parent.height-8.00`, both of them cause the build to throw an error :

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$154(LauncherImpl.java:182)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/user/project/sample/main.fxml:23

at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2579)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
at sample.Main.start(Main.java:18)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$161(LauncherImpl.java:863)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$174(PlatformImpl.java:326)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(PlatformImpl.java:294)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.javafx.fxml.expression.Expression.lambda$subtract$2(Expression.java:868)
at com.sun.javafx.fxml.expression.BinaryExpression.evaluate(BinaryExpression.java:55)
at com.sun.javafx.fxml.expression.ExpressionValue.getValue(ExpressionValue.java:192)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.addListener(ExpressionHelper.java:54)
at javafx.beans.value.ObservableValueBase.addListener(ObservableValueBase.java:55)
at com.sun.javafx.fxml.expression.ExpressionValue.addListener(ExpressionValue.java:201)
at javafx.beans.binding.DoubleBinding.bind(DoubleBinding.java:153)
at javafx.beans.property.DoublePropertyBase$2.<init>(DoublePropertyBase.java:186)
at javafx.beans.property.DoublePropertyBase.bind(DoublePropertyBase.java:184)
at javafx.css.StyleableDoubleProperty.bind(StyleableDoubleProperty.java:75)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processPropertyAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:319)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processInstancePropertyAttributes(FXMLLoader.java:235)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:767)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:2823)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2532)
... 17 more
Exception running application sample.Main
```

I don't understand the reason of this. If I only use `main.parent.height`the code compiles correctly. I also have other lines that use arithmetic operations on FXML correctly.

Comment: When you say, "_this is invalid fxml_", do you mean your get an error when trying to load the FXML file or that your IDE says it's an error?

Comment: @Slaw just a while ago did I realize that it is indeed possible to write a similar syntax. Yes, it errors when trying to build, as for the IntelliJ linter it already fails at understanding most of my references for no reason. I'll update my question.

Comment: It's possible `parent` is null when it parses the expression (and it can't handle that for whatever reason). Try giving your `Pane` an `fx:id` and using that inside the expression instead of `${<id>.parent....}`. That said, you might be better off using a better layout as the parent, such as a `VBox`.

Comment: That worked! Effectively making the need to use a VBox redundant, thanks!

Comment: I would say using a `VBox` would be a _better option_ than binding to the parent. When you bind to the parent you're basically having the children size themselves based on the size of the parent which is backwards in JavaFX. The parents should size the children based on available space and other constraints. With a `VBox` you would just need to add the `TitledPane` and `AnchorPane` and then set the `VBox.vgrow` of the `AnchorPane` to `Priority.ALWAYS`. That will cause the `TitledPane` to size to its pref height and the `AnchorPane` to fill the rest of the space. [cont.]

Comment: And as for the width, a `VBox` tries to size the children to fill all available width when `VBox.fillWidth` is  true (default value).

Comment: Thanks again, I re-checked everything and removed most of the dependent layout attributes using Vbox.